# Error During installation Cordova 3.5 from Command Line interface

Tags: android, cordova

I got following error during installation of cordova 3.5 from command line interface.

[image]

I have also set path
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show full path to bin folder of ANT. see for the variable name `path`, edit it. add one of the following to the end of it's value.

add this to your path variable

```
%ANT_HOME%\bin
```

OR add the full path like

```
C:\ant\bin
```